# Communicating with hardware accessory in the background state continuously in iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, background-process, core-bluetooth, modbus

I am working on an application in which I need to connect and operate hardware drives via Wi-Fi and Bluetooth. As the application needs to communicate with the hardware drives continuously, I need my application to run in the background state as well continuously. For the communication in Wi-Fi mode, we are using the **Modbus library** and for the communication in Bluetooth mode, we are using the Core Bluetooth library.

As Apple has different background modes, for this application I think we can use BLE accessories and background fetch modes both. Background fetch mode to fetch data and support the application to run in the background and BLE accessories mode to communicate with the BLE in the background.

I enabled both the modes and tried to run the application in the background state but it is not running in the background state.

Here is the library which we are using to communicate with our hardware device: https://github.com/ktsakaguchi/SwiftLibModbus

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Core Bluetooth will support your background Bluetooth communication, but if you want continuous Wi-Fi connectivity in the background you will need to misuse a background mode like audio streaming.  This is fine if you are not aiming to be in the App Store.  If you want to be approved for the App Store then there is no way to support continued Wi-Fi connectivity in the background